# Function to find number of nodes below a certain depth of a BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, depth

I'm trying to make a function that will count the number of nodes greater than a certain depth "k".

Here is my code of the function for traversing the tree and a helper function for finding the depth of each node:

```
    int findDepth(BinaryNode * t, int value, int depth){

    if( t == nullptr ){
        return 0;
    }
    if( t->element == value){
        return depth;
    }
    int lowerDepth = findDepth(t->left, value, depth+1);

    if(lowerDepth != 0){
        return lowerDepth;
    }
    lowerDepth = findDepth(t->right, value, depth+1);

    return lowerDepth;

}

int countDeep( BinaryNode * t, int k ){
    int count = 0;
    if (t != nullptr){
        countDeep( t->left, k );
        if (findDepth(t, t->element, 0)){
            count++;
        }
        countDeep( t->right, k );
    }
    return count;
}
```

Right now the function always returns 0 and I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: *Right now the function always returns 0 and I'm not quite sure why.* -- Now is the time to use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

consider this:

```cpp
int countDeep( BinaryNode * t, int k ){
    int count = 0;
    if (t != nullptr){
        countDeep( t->left, k );
        if (findDepth(t, t->element, 0)){
            count++;
        }
        countDeep( t->right, k );
    }
    return count;
}
```

I didn't carefully read other code snippets, yet this function returns either `0` or `1`. Because you discarded the return value of it in recursion. This function can be **seen** as *pure function* (although you modyfy the `count` through `++`), so calling it without using its return value is wrong.

So if another function call this one, the `count` of the function only have one chance to *self-increase*, I didn't inspect into your code, maybe that "only chance" doesn't exist as well.

Comment: maybe you need to add `count +=` before the function call.